# How to format properly date-time column in R using mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to format a string column to a date-time serie.

The row in the column are like this example:  "2019-02-27T19:08:29+000"

(dateTime is the column, the variable)

```
mutate(df,dateTime=as.Date(dateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000"))
```

But the results is:

```
2019-02-27
```

What about the hours, minutes and seconds ?

I need it to apply a filter by date-time

Comment: Use `as.POSIXct(dateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+000")` instead. Note that you had a typo in your format argument - it should only be three `0`s at the end.

Comment: When you do `as.Date()` you are converting to a Date value, and Date's in R don't have hours minutes or seconds. They are just dates. Instead you could use `as.POSIXct()` or some other data structure that supports dates+times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. Just the extra 0 and the `as.Date` command were wrong:

```
library("dplyr")
df <- data.frame(dateTime = "2019-02-27T19:08:29+000",
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mutate(df, dateTime = as.POSIXct(dateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+000"))
```